# How to implement UIPageViewController for apple watch in actionable notification/watchApp?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, apple-watch

Are we able to add buttons and UIPageViewController to the actionable notification Dynamic UI? If yes how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it using relationship segue (next button) using storyboard.

[image]